# How to recursively analyze and modify descendants of a component in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am writing a form wrapper, and I want it to dynamically update the  descendants to add error messages and add error styling for form elements that have validation errors.

I know I can use `React.Children.map` to iterate over the children, but I need to recursively iterate over all descendants, searching for `<input>` and `<button>` elements.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Example:

```
const FormWrapper = (props) => {
  let children = this.props.children;

  if (this.prop.disabled) {
    // Note:  do something here with children to recursively
    // look for form elements, update their props.
  }

  return (
    <form>
      {children}
    </form>
  );
}
```

Usage:

```
<FormWrapper errors={this.errors}>
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col">
      <label>Email:</label>
      <input type="text" name="email">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div className="row">
    <div className="col">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password">
    </div>
  </div>
</FormWrapper>
```

Comment: Ok, turns out I can do this easier by just adding `<fieldset disabled={this.props.disabled}>`.   But I would still like to know how to recursively iterate over all descendants because I want to modify the className on some elements to add error styling.

Comment: This is a pretty strong anti-pattern in react

Comment: Any suggestion on how to do it better?

Comment: Rather than trying to propagate your logic down into the child tree, make your child components smart enough to handle the logic on their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for the ideas, but the actual solution was to use React contexts to push the error messages down to the child components.  Works like a charm.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no clean, optimal and viable way to recurse down the children graph. You will find hacks (such as manually invoking `render` on the children) but nothing clean.